# How can I print out Javascript data into HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print out a JS data into an HTML DOM. 
I couldn't get it to print. What did I do wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>JSON</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // user is the property of obj1
            var obj1 = {
                user: "John",
                age: 26,
                country: "United States"
            };
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = obj1.user + "<hr>";
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="results"></div>         <---- Expected to see John HERE
    </body>

</html>
```

---

In my console

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

[Here is my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/m2y9oqrs/)

Comment: Read the error console. That should indicate the problem. Work backwards from there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m2y9oqrs/1/

Comment: I'm very to new to JS. I totally forgot about my console. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with the Id of `results` has not loaded when the `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = obj1.user + "<hr>";` in the Javascript was called.

So [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) can be used to only execute the Javascript code when the document is loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
        <head>
            <title>JSON</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // user is the property of obj1
                window.onload = function() {
                    var obj1 = {
                        user: "John",
                        age: 26,
                        country: "United States"
                    };
                    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = obj1.user + "<hr>";
                }
            </script>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id="results"></div>         <---- Expected to see John HERE
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

Another way is to put the `script` tag (without the `window.onload`, as in the OP's post) behind `<div id="results"></div>`, so that the div is loaded before the JavaScript code is executed.

Comment: First to answer, the reward is yours. Thank-you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because you have specified the script within the `head` section and so the script is executed before the HTML element with `id="results"` is created

Instead of importing the script in the head section, import it just before the closing body tag `</body>`

```
    <body>
        <div id="results"></div>         <---- Expected to see John HERE
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // user is the property of obj1
            var obj1 = {
                user: "John",
                age: 26,
                country: "United States"
            };
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = obj1.user + "<hr>";
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be more than 1 way to solve this, but I solve mine by 
wait for the window to load:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    // my JSCodeHERE
}
```

Comment: Upvoting because I didn't knew window.onload executes after the page is loaded completely